# Error handling on missing dataset file

Tags: open-data-cube

I'm working with the [sentinel-2-l2a-cogs](https://registry.opendata.aws/sentinel-2-l2a-cogs/) dataset hosted on AWS, trying to index some areas taking advantage of the [STAC API](https://earth-search.aws.element84.com/v0/collections/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs) provided by Element84.

Unfortunately, I ran across the item [S2B_36LUM_20180701_0_L2A](https://earth-search.aws.element84.com/v0/collections/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/items/S2B_36LUM_20180701_0_L2A/) that comes with broken URLs (404) to the related COG files.

Having indexed this item into ODC, when I do a `dc.load()` on that area and time frame I get an error:

```
Error opening source dataset: \
https://sentinel-cogs.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/36/L/UM/2018/7/S2B_36LUM_20180701_0_L2A/SCL.tif

CPLE_OpenFailedError: \
'/vsicurl/https://sentinel-cogs.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/36/L/UM/2018/7/S2B_36LUM_20180701_0_L2A/SCL.tif' \
does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
```

Is there something I can do to let datacube just ignore that dataset and keep loading whatever other dataset is available?

Answer (score 1):

The way to handle this is to add the argument `skip_broken_datasets=True` to your `dc.load()`.

As it says, this will ignore the broken datasets.

The next thing to do is to report the broken datasets to Element 84 in their [cirrus repository](https://github.com/cirrus-geo/cirrus-earth-search/issues).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!
I've had already sent an email to opendata@element84.com, but I'll do it there as well, thank you again